# Qubes OS OpenVPN UDP works from terminal, not from NetworkManager

Tags: vpn, openvpn, networkmanager

TCP works either way.

I've fresh installed Qubes OS 3.2.
I am trying to connect to NORDVPN from the sys-net.
If I open a terminal and type "sudo openvpn --config us512.nordvpn.com.udp1194.ovpn" (asks for user and password), the connection is successful.

However, if I click on the NetworkManager icon --> VPN Connections --> Configure VPN... --> Add --> Import a saved VPN configuration... --> point to us512.nordvpn.com.udp1194.ovpn --> type user and password.... it does not work when I try to connect.

sudo journalctl -u NetworkManager shows:
 - "TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)"
 - "TLS Error: TLS handshake failed"

Does anyone have a pointer on what could be going on?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is super weird.

When adding the configuration by importing it through the GUI, the connection would not establish.

However, I ran the following command to import it from command line:

sudo nmcli connection import type openvpn file us512.nordvpn.com.udp1194.ovpn

I got a successful import message. Then, I tried to establish the connection from NetworkManager and it worked fine. Bug in NetworkManager?